# Multiple paginations in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

How can I make different paginations in single page?

This is the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
    $categories = Category::all();    
    $randomPosts = RandomPost::orderByRaw("RAND()")->paginate(2);
    return view('posts.index', compact('posts', 'categories','randomPosts'));
}
```

When I'm in a page, and let' say click second page then both paginations change to second page. What I want to do here is to make that when I press second page on $posts then the $randomPosts will still stay in 1st page and not in the 2nd. I can't find a way how to do that on Laravel 5.1 version.

All in all I want to make two seperate paginations in one single page.

Comment: You might want to check similar question for laravel 4 http://stackoverflow.com/questins/24086269/laravel-multiple-pagination-in-one-page

Comment: This is the correct link (there is a **o** missing) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086269/laravel-multiple-pagination-in-one-page

Comment: It's not working for Laravel 5.1

Comment: Did you find out an answer for this @feknaz?