# How to remove query string page from the first page of laravel pagination?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.4

I'm using [laravel-5.4](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.4) pagination like the following:

```
public function index()
    {
        $jobs = Job::paginate(5);
        return view('job.index', compact('jobs'));
    }
```

In the view:

```
{{ $jobs->links() }}
```

There is a problem of generating two typical pages: `/job` and `/job?page=1` the two page has the same contents.

I want to do anything that removes the query string `page` from the first page of the pagination.

I have tried the following:

```
if ($jobs->onFirstPage()){
  $jobs->setPageName('');
}
```

But this corrupt the pagination, i.e the links of pages does not load correctly and the query string value remains for all pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The effective solution for this issue that I have found is to **edit the pagination template**.

First publish the pagination template from the vendors using the following command from the root of the project:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

Now a file at `resources/views/vendor/pagination/default.blade.php` should be found and it could be edited like the following using `str_replace()` for the urls of each page and back navigation button:

```
<li><a href="{{str_replace('?page=1','',$paginator->previousPageUrl())}}" title="{{__('Previous')}}" rel="prev">{{$foxPrev}}</a></li>
```

and

```
 <li><a href="{{str_replace('?page=1','',$url)}}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
```

#### Update:

A bug was found with `?page=10` so instead of using `str_replace` we should using `preg_replace` like the following:

```
<li><a href="{{preg_replace('/\?page=[1]$/','',$url)}}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
```

#### Update 2:

In case of using any customized name for the page number parameter other than `page`, we could use the paginator getter for the [$pageName](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html) property like the following in the pagination template:

```
<li><a href="{{preg_replace('/\?'.$paginator->getPageName().'=[1]$/','',$url)}}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
```

To know more about how to use more than one pagination on the same page or how to customize the page number parameter `$pageName` from view, checkout [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49136215/1592845)

Comment: Thank you! But I think this is better;

`<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ preg_replace('/(\?|\&)page=[1]$/','',$url) }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>`

Comment: Expression '/((\?|\&)page=[1]$)|(page=[1]($|\&))/' OR '/((\?|\&)'.$paginator->getPageName().'=[1]$)|('.$paginator->getPageName().'=[1]($|\&))/' will cover all the cases. For example: '...?page=1', '...?page=1&brand=2', '...?brand=2&page=1&filter=3', '...?brand=2&page=1'. And it will not react on 'page=10' in any position.

Comment: I don't understand how this question is upvoted when removing all parameters from link will give us URL to the same page with same parameters. Like if we are on the page ?page=2 it will give us same link on Page 1.

Answer (score 4):

You can extend **LengthAwarePaginator** method **url($page)**

```
/**
 * Get the URL for a given page number.
 *
 * @param  int  $page
 * @return string
 */
public function url($page)
{
    if ($page <= 0) {
        $page = 1;
    }

    // If we have any extra query string key / value pairs that need to be added
    // onto the URL, we will put them in query string form and then attach it
    // to the URL. This allows for extra information like sortings storage.
    $parameters = ($page > 1) ? [$this->pageName => $page] : [];

    if (count($this->query) > 0) {
        $parameters = array_merge($this->query, $parameters);
    }

    return rtrim($this->path
        .(Str::contains($this->path, '?') ? '&' : '?')
        .http_build_query($parameters, '', '&')
        .$this->buildFragment(), '?');
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Remove `['page' => 1]` from the `$parameters` array, and then remove the trailing `?` if necessary. EZPZ. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

improved Aksi answer

app/Services/CustomLengthAwarePaginator.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CustomLengthAwarePaginator extends LengthAwarePaginator
{
    /**
     * Get the URL for a given page number.
     *
     * @param  int  $page
     * @return string
     */
    public function url($page)
    {
        if ($page <= 0) {
            $page = 1;
        }

        // If we have any extra query string key / value pairs that need to be added
        // onto the URL, we will put them in query string form and then attach it
        // to the URL. This allows for extra information like sortings storage.
        $parameters = ($page > 1) ? [$this->pageName => $page] : [];

        if (count($this->query) > 0) {
            $parameters = array_merge($this->query, $parameters);
        }

        return $this->path()
            . (count($parameters) > 0
                ? (Str::contains($this->path(), '?') ? '&' : '?')
                : '')
            . Arr::query($parameters)
            . $this->buildFragment();
    }
}
```

in AppServiceProvider.php or another

```
public function boot()
{
    app()->bind(LengthAwarePaginator::class, CustomLengthAwarePaginator::class);
}
```

Comment: This looks like the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

add canonical tag in  if you care SEO

i don't have any idea...

```
if($pageNum==1){
    return redirect()->to($path);
}
```

$pageNum id get Request or urself Class

$path = "/jobs"

Comment: This for SEO, so what's about extra resources and traffic consumption to retrieve the same content?! Unfortunately this is not the ideal solution that I have to find.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, give a name to the route which leads to your function:

```
Route::get('/yourRoute','YourController@foo')->name('yourRouteName');
```

Then, In your function in the controller, use this:

```
public function foo() {
    if( request()->page=='1' )
    {
            return redirect()->route('yourRouteName',[$id]);
    }
     else {
            // Your function content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
{{ $jobs->links() }}
```

To

```
{{ $jobs->nextPageUrl() }}
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify the view like this:

```
@if ($page==1)
   <a href="{{ str_replace('?page=1', '', $url) }}">{{ $page }}</a>
@else
   <a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following works and takes into account `page=10` issues:

After you [export your pagination views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view), make the following 2 modifications:

**MODIFICATION 1**

Replace this:

`{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}`

with this:

`{{ preg_replace('/(?:(&|\\?)page=[1])(?!\\d)/ui','', $paginator->previousPageUrl()) }}`

**MODIFICATION 2**

Replace this:

`{{ $url }}`

with this:

`{{ preg_replace('/(?:(&|\\?)page=[1])(?!\\d)/ui','', $url ) }}`

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way:

```
{{ $posts->currentPage() == 2 ? route('home') : $posts->previousPageUrl() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Middleware by using this command

```
php artisan make:middleware RemovePageQuery
```

Write this code inside middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RemovePageQuery
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->page == 1)
        {
            return redirect(url()->current());
        }
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Add middleware global in App/Http/Kernel.php inside $middleware.

```
 protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\RemovePageQuery::class, //Here
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching to fix similar issue to prevent content duplication but for symfony not laravel. I fixed it in my way and decided to publish it. May be it will help somebody.

In symfony I use KNP paginator. It provides paginator template, like this:

```
     <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): page})) }}">{{ page }}</a>
```

'Query' array contains route params and the task is to remove page param if it == 1.

Very simple:

```
    {% set page_seo = (page == 1) ? null : page %}
    <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): page_seo})) }}">{{ page }}</a>
```

Actually - set to null page if it == 1.

Answer (score 0):

By this way you can remove form field from the request in Laravel Controller. **It will work 100%**. You will get in request without page param.

```
   $request->request->remove('page');
```

Answer (score 0):

Better answer than @SaidbakR has provided, as I it's not right. Why? Because you will receive link for the same page as URL will be empty. And for example if you make request from url?page=2, you'll get link to same url?page=2 where link to first page must appear.

My easy variant:

1. Also publish pagination views: `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`
2. Go to `/views/vendor/pagination/default.blade.php`
3. Add `elseif` case to previous page link:

   ```
        @elseif($paginator->currentPage() === 2)
            <li class="pagination-next-prev link">
                <a class="prev page-url" href="?{{ http_build_query(Arr::except(Request::query(), 'page')) }}" rel="prev"
                   aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">
                    Prev
                </a>
            </li>
        @else
   ```
4. Add similar `elseif` to array of links:

   ```
   @elseif(1 === $page)
      <li class="page">
          <a class="page-url" href="?{{ http_build_query(Arr::except(Request::query(), 'page')) }}">
              {{ $page }}
          </a>
      </li>
    @else
   ```
5. This case is also working if you are using ajax request to another page for pagination.
6. Done

You will have link to the page you opened, but without params. Yes it will be showed as `?` in the URL, but it's fair price to avoid duplications of URLs, as link with just question mark for google same as without.

Answer (score 0):

run `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`

update `resources/views/vendor/pagination/bootstrap-5.blade.php` to this

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <nav class="d-flex justify-items-center justify-content-between">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-fill d-sm-none">
            <ul class="pagination">
                {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
                @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                    <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true">
                        <span class="page-link">@lang('pagination.previous')</span>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="{{ preg_replace('/[\&\?]page=[1]$/','',$paginator->previousPageUrl()) }}" rel="prev">@lang('pagination.previous')</a>
                    </li>
                @endif

                {{-- Next Page Link --}}
                @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next">@lang('pagination.next')</a>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true">
                        <span class="page-link">@lang('pagination.next')</span>
                    </li>
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="d-none flex-sm-fill d-sm-flex align-items-sm-center justify-content-sm-between">


            <div>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
                    @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                        <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">
                            <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
                        </li>
                    @else
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="{{ preg_replace('/[\&\?]page=[1]$/','',$paginator->previousPageUrl()) }}" rel="prev" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">&lsaquo;</a>
                        </li>
                    @endif

                    {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
                    @foreach ($elements as $element)
                        {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
                        @if (is_string($element))
                            <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span class="page-link">{{ $element }}</span></li>
                        @endif

                        {{-- Array Of Links --}}
                        @if (is_array($element))
                            @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                                @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                                    <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">{{ $page }}</span></li>
                                @else
                                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ preg_replace('/[\&\?]page=[1]$/','',$url) }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    @endforeach

                    {{-- Next Page Link --}}
                    @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">&rsaquo;</a>
                        </li>
                    @else
                        <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">
                            <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p class="small text-muted">
                    {!! __('Showing') !!}
                    <span class="fw-semibold">{{ $paginator->firstItem() }}</span>
                    {!! __('to') !!}
                    <span class="fw-semibold">{{ $paginator->lastItem() }}</span>
                    {!! __('of') !!}
                    <span class="fw-semibold">{{ $paginator->total() }}</span>
                    {!! __('results') !!}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
@endif
```