# Laravel 6 multiple pagination in one page

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I want to create multiple pagination in one page, `info` pagination is working perfectly. but 
`berita` pagination is linked to `info` and always showing `info` page instead of `berita` page.

**Controller**

```
$infos = Info::paginate(4, ['*'], 'info');
$beritas = Berita::paginate(4, ['*'], 'berita');
```

**View**

```
{{$infos->appends(['info' => $infos->currentPage()])->links()}}
{{$beritas->appends(['berita' => $beritas->currentPage()])->links()}}
```

> EDITED

**Info**

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="« Sebelumnya">
   <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">‹</span>
</li>
<li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">1</span></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000?info=2">2</a></li>
<li class="page-item">
   <a class="page-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000?info=2" rel="next" aria-label="Berikutnya »">›</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Berita**

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="page-item">
   <a class="page-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000?berita=1" rel="prev" aria-label="« Sebelumnya">‹</a>
</li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000?berita=1">1</a></li>
<li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">2</span></li>
<li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="Berikutnya »">
   <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">›</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

> EDITED

Now it works, but it always show one `info data` inside `berita` pagination.

[image: pagination screenshot]

Comment: Can you post the code of both pagination buttons which will be generated by blade?

Comment: done, is that what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Multiple Pagination in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086269/laravel-multiple-pagination-in-one-page)

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: i cant find environment inside ```vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/ ```anyway

Comment: I don't recommend to use two laravel paginations in one page. It isn't build for that. Make two pages or use serve the data with a rest api and consume it with js to achieve two datatable with pagination on one page.

Comment: i see, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible as long as you keep track of the page value for the opposite set:

```
{{$infos->appends(['info' => $infos->currentPage(), 'berita' => $beritas->currentPage()])->links()}}

{{$beritas->appends(['berita' => $beritas->currentPage(), 'info' => $infos->currentPage()])->links()}}
```

I'll try and test this theory out later if I find time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to append the other pagination value not the one you are in
like this:

```
{{$infos->appends(['berita' => $beritas->currentPage()])->links()}}
{{$beritas->appends(['info' => $infos->currentPage()])->links()}}
```